# how to implement layout shadow in xml layer list?

Tags: java, android, layout, shadow

i need to make a menu shadow like in the photo. how can i implement it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is the one I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
        <item>
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />
                <corners android:radius="7dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <!-- White Top color -->
        <item android:bottom="5px">
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
                <corners android:radius="7dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: how do i blur the shadow color?

Answer (score 0):

I just made this drawable for this case

**shadow.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#0c6bba"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And set it to the navigation drawer like this

```
navigationDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```